# Routing static urls in javascript files in symfony

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, assetic, symfony-routing

I have some javascript files in my `Symfonyt2` project that load some reources dynamically from the javascript file.
for example:

```
$('.records_list').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": "../shared/js/datatables.persian.json"
    }
});
```

the url `../shared/js/datatables.persian.json` works in pages with url like `/test` but in pages with url ike `/test2/action` it fails.
How can i fix this?
Is there a tool like `cssrewrite` filter for assetic?
or can I make routes for such urls?

Comment: Did you try: `"url": "/shared/js/datatables.persian.json"`?

Comment: @dfsq: this is related to domain but I need to move the pages to different folders so I dont want to change all of these on every move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have too many cases like this, you can store your file path with twig in a hidden div for example :

```
<div id="file-store" style="display:none;" data-value="{{ asset('shared/js/persian.json') }}"></div>
```

And retrieve it in js :

```
var sharedFile = $('#file-store').attr('data-value');
$('.records_list').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "url": sharedFile
    }
});
```

If you have a lot of cases like this, then you can make use of the **FOSJsRoutingBundle** :

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle